# Accessing Amazon Connect from inside of VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-connect

I'm trying to make a call from a lambda function within VPC using `boto3.start_outbound_voice_contact()`. Since the lambda function cannot reach whatever outside the VPC, simply invoking the `boto3.start_outbound_voice_contact()` function.

I have came up with placing a VPC endpoint between lambda and Amazon Connect. But I am not sure which of the following types of endpoint `boto3.start_outbound_voice_contact()` belongs to.

- Amazon AppIntegrations
- Customer Profiles
- Outbound campaigns
- Voice ID
- Wisdom

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/vpc-interface-endpoints.html

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have attached the AWS Lambda function to the VPC? If you detach the function, it will be automatically connected to the Internet and can therefore call the AWS API endpoints.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, thank you for the comment. I attached Lambda function to the VPC because I want the function to access RDS instance privately.

Comment: Ah! Yes, in that case, you will either need a NAT Gateway or a VPC Endpoint.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein When I use a VPC Endpoint, which of the following services shoud I choose? com.amazonaws.region.app-integrations, com.amazonaws.region.profile, com.amazonaws.region.connect-campaigns, com.amazonaws.region.voiceid, com.amazonaws.region.wisdom

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know enough about Amazon Connect to answer that.